# Transfer Ticket To Another Queue Request Tracker 4

Tags: perl, scripting, rt

I am looking for a clean way of transferring a ticket submitted in one queue to another queue. For example, if a ticket is submitted to our Collections Department queue I want to be able to transfer the ticket directly to the Managers Queue, and not have the ticket appear at all in the Collections Queue.

Is there some feature in RT4 that will let me do this or can it only be done with a custom SCRIP?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an email address set up for your Collections Department queue, you can update the alias that pipes the email into RT. Update the --queue value to "Managers Queue".

If tickets are created in the Collections Department queue via the web interface, you could create a scrip that would automatically move them. In the Collections Department queue, create a new scrip with a Condition of "On Create" and a blank template. For the Action, select User Defined, then in the Custom action preparation code put something like:

```
my ($status, $msg) = $self->TicketObj->SetQueue("Managers Queue");
if ( not $status ) {
    RT::Logger->error("Could not reassign queue: $msg");
}
return 1;
```